# What encoding is used by functions such as glGetString and glGetShaderInfoLog

Tags: opengl

OpenGL has a few functions like `glGetString` and `glGetShaderInfoLog` that return strings. What form of text encoding is used for these?

I assume, given that they're returned as a `GLchar*`, that it is ASCII encoded text contained in the return value but is this specified anywhere?

As a second and related point, what text encoding is expected by functions such as `glShaderSource` and `glBindAttribLocation`. Do GLSL programs have to be encoded in ASCII or can it be UTF-8?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241598/vertex-shader-not-compiling-due-to-a-non-ascii-character. Is seems `glShaderSource` does not handle anything other than plain ASCII well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenGL 4.3 Compatibility Profile Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.compatibility.20130214.pdf), section 22.2, page 627:

> String queries return pointers to UTF-8 encoded, null-terminated static strings describing properties of the current GL context.

As far as I can see the spec doesn't mention the encoding of `glGetShaderInfoLog()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the GLSL 4.40 language specification

> The source character set used for the OpenGL shading languages is Unicode in the UTF-8 encoding
> scheme.

https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf

That said, I doubt you have much luck puttying ÅÄÖ in variable names but you should be able to have comments with non ASCII data in them.