# Print opengl shader compile log with wprintf

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, lpwstr

Following the tutorials at [opengl-tutorial.org](http://opengl-tutorial.org)
, realize that I can't print the shader compile log directly with printf because I'm doing it in a windows desktop application. I tried to convert it to a LPWSTR using this method:

```
//compile the shader
glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &pFsCode, NULL);
glCompileShader(fShader);

//check shader compilation
glGetShaderiv(fShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
glGetShaderiv(fShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen);
if (logLen > 0) {
    //get compile log
    vector<char> fErr(logLen + 1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fShader, logLen, NULL, &fErr[0]);

    //try to convert log to LPWSTR
    wchar_t msg[100];
    swprintf(msg, sizeof(msg) / sizeof(*msg), L"%s\n", &fErr[0]);

    //print it
    wprintf(msg);
}
```

For some reason, I get this output:

`⤱㨠攠牲牯䌠㄰ㄲ›瘣牥楳湯㌠〰洠獵⁴敢映汯潬敷⁤祢攠ੳ⠰⤲㨠攠牲牯䌠㈰㄰›湵畳灰牯整⁤敶獲潩⁮〳ਰ⠰⤲㨠攠牲牯䌠〰〰›祳瑮硡攠牲牯‬湵硥数瑣摥✠✨‬硥数瑣湩⁧㨢∺愠⁴潴敫⁮⠢ਢ⠰⤴㨠攠牲牯䌠㔷㈳`

Can someone please tell me why I get this corrupt output?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not converting the `char`s to `wchar_t`s using `swprintf(..., "%s\n", ...)` because, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx `%s` means the following:

> When used with printf functions, specifies a single-byte or multi-byte character string; when used with wprintf functions, specifies a wide-character string. Characters are displayed up to the first null character or until the precision value is reached.

As you're indeed using a `*wprintf` function here, `%s` already expects a wide string, but you give it a non-wide string. So the ascii text (in this case `1) : error C0121: #version 300 must be followed by ...`) is interpreted as wide string instead, resulting in garbage.

According to the same webpage, `%S` might be the quickest fix to resolve your problem here ("when used with wprintf functions, specifies a single-byte or multi-byte character string" - what `%s` is for normal printf).

Comment: Thank you for you help. I guess it makes sense that escape codes in wprintf would be different.

Answer (score 0):

As @genpfault explains in his [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16068464/3871028) The OpenGL specification speaks about `*GetString` commands returning UFT-8 strings. Nothing is said about `glGetShaderInfoLog`, but it seems reasonably that it also returns a UTF-8 encoded string.

Even if it is ASCII it will be the same when converted to UTF-8, because UTF-8 first 127 codes are the same as ASCII codes.

Your best option would be to print UTF-8 strings, if that was possible in C++ without any conversion. But up today it isn't in Windows, which uses UFT-16 internally, or Linux and its UTF-32 usage.

For the conversion, use [std::codecvt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt). For an example, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921979/how-to-convert-utf-8-encoded-stdstring-to-utf-16-stdstring)